# Swift packages with the same name causing errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to import two packages, both called `PushNotifications`, into Swift Package Manager. I need them both. However as they both have the same name I get the errors:

> Multiple products named 'PushNotifications` in: 'push-notifications-server-swift', 'push-notifications-swift'

> Multiple targets named 'PushNotifications` in: 'push-notifications-server-swift', 'push-notifications-swift'

Trying to add the other one, even with a different URL, shows the error below and disables the `Add Package` button.

> The project 'my-project' already contains this package dependency.

I have tried importing one with cocoa pods but it doesn't make any difference. I cannot edit the `Package.swift` files for either of them as they are not my packages and have been directly linked to Xcode via GitHub

These are the packages I have installed

[image: 1]

How can I rename or namespace the Swift packages so that I can import both?

Comment: Fork one of the packages and give it a different name

Comment: As a heads-up you should not include `push-notifications-server-swift` in a client app.  It should be used in your server to send push notifications.  It is not secure to have your iOS app send Beams messages directly.  The user should authenticate to your back-end server and invoke a service on that server that calls the Beams server API.  If you implement the server api directly in your iOS app then you expose your api key and secret.

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/cant-consume-two-swift-packages-with-the-same-name/40408/1